# Converting a dynamic date column to other format in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

1. I have a dataframe

`df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,{'dt_created':'2018-06-29T11:43:57.530Z','rand_col1':'val1'}),(4,5,6,{'rand_col2':'val2','rand_col3':'val3'}),(7,8,9,{'dt_uploaded':'2018-06-19T11:43:57.530Z','rand_col1':'val2'})]`

2. The json column may or may not have a date column and the date key is dynamic
3. I would like to check if any value in the json matches the date format and if it matches would like to convert it to other format

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved as easy way with UDF function

**Method 1**

This code try to find a date in your JSON and then transform to a new datetime (on my example I putted it in a new column)

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark

@f.udf()
def parse(column: dict):
    for value in column.values():
        if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z', value):
            return datetime \
                .strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') \
                .strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    return None

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3, {'dt_created': '2018-06-29T11:43:57.530Z', 'rand_col1': 'val1'}),
                            (4, 5, 6, {'rand_col2': 'val2', 'rand_col3': 'val3'}),
                            (7, 8, 9, {'dt_uploaded': '2018-06-19T11:43:57.530Z', 'rand_col1': 'val2'})],
                           ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df = df.withColumn('parse_dt', parse(f.col('D')))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+--------------------+----------+
|  A|  B|  C|                   D|  parse_dt|
+---+---+---+--------------------+----------+
|  1|  2|  3|[dt_created -> 20...|2018-06-29|
|  4|  5|  6|[rand_col2 -> val...|      null|
|  7|  8|  9|[dt_uploaded -> 2...|2018-06-19|
+---+---+---+--------------------+----------+
```

**Method 2**

If you only want replace the date inside of JSON:

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType


@f.udf(returnType=MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
def parse(column: dict):
    for key, value in column.items():
        if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z', value):
            column[key] = datetime \
                .strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') \
                .strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    return column


df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3, {'dt_created': '2018-06-29T11:43:57.530Z', 'rand_col1': 'val1'}),
                            (4, 5, 6, {'rand_col2': 'val2', 'rand_col3': 'val3'}),
                            (7, 8, 9, {'dt_uploaded': '2018-06-19T11:43:57.530Z', 'rand_col1': 'val2'})],
                           ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df = df.withColumn('D', parse(f.col('D')))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+----------------------------------------------+
|A  |B  |C  |D                                             |
+---+---+---+----------------------------------------------+
|1  |2  |3  |[dt_created -> 2018-06-29, rand_col1 -> val1] |
|4  |5  |6  |[rand_col2 -> val2, rand_col3 -> val3]        |
|7  |8  |9  |[dt_uploaded -> 2018-06-19, rand_col1 -> val2]|
+---+---+---+----------------------------------------------+
```